# Oracle REFCURSOR error with declare and setting up variables

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, ref-cursor

I am rather new to Oracle, I use sql server for years.   I been trying to get a cursor loop to work.  I had found an example that is in a Function, but for testing, i'm not wanting to create the function just yet.

I was hoping this type of syntax would work,   what am i doing wrong?   I'm using PL/SQL Developer

```
declare 
c_actual REFCURSOR;  
v_crkt_nb log_step_circuit.crkt_nb%TYPE;
v_string  VARCHAR2(50);

v_string := '';

open c_actual for 

SELECT 
  u.LGN_ID_NM 
  FROM work_folder f,
   trouble_call    t,
   doc_log_step    d,
   impacted_device i,
   user_assignment a,
   user_role       r,
   oms_user        u,
   service_location s
 WHERE t.impct_dev_k = i.impct_dev_k
    and i.doc_log_stp_k = d.doc_log_stp_k
    and d.work_fldr_k = f.work_fldr_k
    and s.locatn_k = t.locatn_k
    and f.work_fldr_k = a.work_fldr_k
    and a.user_role_k = r.user_role_k
    and FOLDER_PKG.TroubleCallCount(f.work_fldr_k) = 1
    and r.lgn_id_nm = u.lgn_id_nm
    AND t.oms_tcall_k = 563815
    and f.work_fldr_k in
    (select work_fldr_k
      from work_folder
     WHERE work_folder.fldr_stts_c in ('NEW', 'IN PROGRESS'))
     AND ROLE_C = 'TRBLSHTR' and a.unasn_d is null;

     LOOP
       FETCH c_actual INTO v_crkt_nb;
     EXIT WHEN c_actual%NOTFOUND;  

     v_string := substr(v_string || v_crkt_nb || '  ',1, 50);
     END LOOP;

     v_string := trim(v_string);

     CLOSE c_actual;
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look below.

```
declare 
v_crkt_nb log_step_circuit.crkt_nb%TYPE;
v_string  VARCHAR2(500);
cursor c1 is
  SELECT u.LGN_ID_NM 
  FROM work_folder f,
   trouble_call    t,
   doc_log_step    d,
   impacted_device i,
   user_assignment a,
   user_role       r,
   oms_user        u,
   service_location s
 WHERE t.impct_dev_k = i.impct_dev_k
    and i.doc_log_stp_k = d.doc_log_stp_k
    and d.work_fldr_k = f.work_fldr_k
    and s.locatn_k = t.locatn_k
    and f.work_fldr_k = a.work_fldr_k
    and a.user_role_k = r.user_role_k
    and FOLDER_PKG.TroubleCallCount(f.work_fldr_k) = 1
    and r.lgn_id_nm = u.lgn_id_nm
    AND t.oms_tcall_k = 563815
    and f.work_fldr_k in
    (select work_fldr_k
      from work_folder
     WHERE work_folder.fldr_stts_c in ('NEW', 'IN PROGRESS'))
     AND ROLE_C = 'TRBLSHTR' and a.unasn_d is null;
Begin
v_string := '';

FOR i in c1

     LOOP

       EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;  

       v_string := substr(v_string || v_crkt_nb || '  ',1, 50);
     END LOOP;

     v_string := trim(v_string);

end;
/
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Overall good answer.  For the OP I would try to explain what and why your doing it so they learn a little bit of what they did wrong though.    They also probably want to get rid of   EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;    not needed, and then with pl/sql    use a File-New-Test Window and add in dbms_output.put_line(v_string);